Github pages Jekyll theme "Minima" navigation not showing
On the Github pages with the jekyll "Minima" theme, I am trying to make the navigation menu points ("header_pages" configuration) work.
I work entirely in the browser on github.com and have tried to avoid html as much as possible.
This is my _config.yml file (in the root directory):
title: title
description: description
remote_theme: minima
header_pages:
  - about.md

This is the page I want to have the navigation link lead to:
about.md (also in the root directory)
---
title: About
layout: default
---
This is...

The Minima theme works, however, the navigation points do not show up like in the Minima Demo page top right corner "About" (https://jekyll.github.io/minima/).
I have tried copying all steps in the Minima theme repo ( https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_config.yml, https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/about.md )
for example, changing the front of the about.md file to
---
layout: page
title: About
permalink: /about/
---

But the navigation still does not show up.
Thanks for any help to make a navigation button to the about-subpage appear! :)

Have you seen https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/how-to-get-header-pages-in-minima-to-pull-from-pages-directory/2433 ?

Hi! Thanks, I haven't seen this, but my about.md is in the root directory. Shouldn't it then work?

Right. Must be somethingn else then. I added an answer.

You don't have a Gemfile in your repo, so I'm not quite sure which versions of Jekyll GitHub pages ends up using. But if I try locally (i.e. on my laptop) with Jekyll 3.9.5, it tells me:

Remote Theme: "minima" is not a valid remote theme

(You see the same thing in GitHub Actions tab -> "Build with Jekyll".)
Changing remote_theme: minima to theme: minima fixed this for me.

Thank you so much, changing to "theme: minima" fixed it! :)
